# Creating a slug field in database tied to name field

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a django project for which I'm trying to update the database tables without using any migration tools.  I'm adding a 'slug' field to a model which simply references it's name, and I was intending on doing so by replicating what was in another table that already has a slug for.

So, I have an existing table 'gym' in the database as follows

```
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| gym_name | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| gym_slug | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created  | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and I have another table 'wall' in the database as follows:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| wall_name | varchar(50) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| gym_id    | int(11)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| created   | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| modified  | datetime    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

This would get me part of the way there:

```
ALTER TABLE wall ADD COLUMN wall_slug varchar(50);
```

But I'm not certain how to figure out where the foreign key in the first table is referencing and thus where I should point the new one.

End goal: the wall_slug field tied to a unique wall_name field. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by this:
"But I'm not certain how to figure out where the foreign key in the first table is referencing and thus where I should point the new one."  You're adding a text field, not a foreign key, right?  Also, do you mean "ALTER TABLE wall ADD COLUMN wall_slug varchar(50)" ?

Comment: With regards to the latter question, yes - I just edited it to reflect the appropriate query.  As for your first question, I might be misunderstanding what the table is showing me, but it looks like gym.gym_name and gym.gym_slug aren't just related at the model level but also at the DB level.  I'm assuming I have to do the same to somehow relate wall.wall_name to wall.wall_slug, but I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

class Wall(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.slug == '':
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Wall, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will generate for you a slug based on the name when saving. It also protects you from changing the slug next time you change the name, so URLs remain stable and unchanged.

Comment: 1 question: is there a reason you changed slug to a CharField instead of a SlugField?  And 1 point: I wasn't so worried about the django model as I was about the DB.  My primary concern is that the gym table, as created by syncdb, appears to have a MUL value for key and I don't know how to properly recreate that in the wall table.